# SIMPLE "Share on Facebook"

Tags: iphone, facebook

Is there a SIMPLE way to share an image and text on Facebook. I used to use an early version of Sharekit but it has since evolved into a huge library which is a lot of work to setup.
Is there another simple option that doesn't require to setup and change a ton of settings just to have a simple "Share on Facebook" function? I don't need twitter and the gazillion other options that Sharekit includes today... And I personally think that Sharekit is getting very bloated... the installation alone is like a 10 page long guide.

Comment: Are you kidding? I have used ShareKit since the beginning and it literally takes 5 minutes to set up. You just have to know what your doing. It will take the same or less amount of time to install Sharekit and get a post to Facebook working than it will trying to use the FBConnect files alone.

Comment: No, I'm not kidding you. I used to use sharekit and it was super easy - But taking a look at the latest version and this install guide: https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit. Thats a joke, installing git to get some modules, added bundles different places, dragging projects in, settings up paths and other keys etc. etc. And after all that was done it STILL didn't work... Thats is overly complex and uneeded for something as simple as "Share image on FB".

Comment: I got it done in less than 5 minutes and I have it memorized :P Anyway, I recommend that using git is the way to go anyway since it is easier to update anyway.

Comment: @iBradApps - please post working instructions for non-git users (I would use git, but we have a legacy repo in svn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoacontrols has a few Facebook-specific share controls.

The prettiest (IMHO) is this one:

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/asfbpostcontroller

Looks really good to me, though I must admit I haven't tried it yet. Setup should be simple as it only deals with Facebook.

EDIT: Here are some more:

- http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/bcdsharesheet
- http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ftshare-an-easy-way-to-share-using-facebook-twitter-and-mails
- http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ddshareviewcontroller